# Clustered Indexing

Tags: sql-server, database

Does Clustered index needs one extra table to sort/keep the rows data?
When it does the sorting , on each Insert or delete statement or when ?
How clustered index store data and how it is different from Non-clustered one.

Answer (score 8):

- The data is the clustered index
- Index sort is on creation/rebuild only
- Inserts may create page splits and pointers
- Deletes leave gaps
- Gaps are removed by index rebuild
- Clustered = data sorted as per definition
- Non-clustered = points to clustered index and has it's own sort

[Starter article on Simple-Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/)

[A more in depth article on Simple-Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/brads-sure-guide-to-indexes/)

Edit:
[Another Simple-Talk article on index maintenance](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/don%E2%80%99t-forget-to-maintain-your-indexes/)

Comment: Then when index rebuild is done?
Is it manual or automatically done by Database server?

Comment: You need to trigger index rebuild - it's never done automatically

Comment: +1 - excellent resources - couldn't have said it better myself :-)

Comment: Thanks. Added link to index maintenance.

Comment: How to rebuild the index manually in Sql Server. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: In SQL Mgmt Studio, open the Object EXplorer, find the database and table you're interested in, open the table node, open the "Indexes" node, pick the right index, right-click - in the context menu, you have two option "Reorganize" and "Rebuild"

Comment: If you want to semi-automate the process, check out Michelle Ufford's excellent Index Defrag Script here: http://sqlfool.com/2009/06/index-defrag-script-v30/